# Fragment not replacing parent activity's container layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have an activity in my android app, in which i have placed a RecyclerView Widget inside a Frame Layout. The Frame Layout is acting as the Parent Container.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
tools:context="com.example.asad.comppecv2.AdminActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/default_toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_body"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/default_toolbar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_below="@id/default_toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
</FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my code for instantiating the RecyclerView in my activity.

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(Participant_Data_List,getApplicationContext());
recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

This activity contains a navigation drawer, from which i load different fragments.

What i want is that, when a fragment loads, it replaces the contents of my Frame Layout. Here is code responsible for loading the fragment.

```
private void initiateFragment(){
    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

Here is a picture of my activity, with the RecyclerView instantiated by default when the activity laods.

[image]

Here is a picture of the fragment which i want to load and replace the recycler view.

[image]

But when i load this fragment, instead of replacing, it overlaps on the recycler view.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

**UPDATE #2**

This is the block of code responsible for handling fragments

```
public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
result.setSelection(position,false);
clearStack();
switch (position) {
    case 1:
        fragment = new admin_fragment_data_entry();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new admin_fragment_data_edit();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new admin_fragment_judge_data();
        break;
    case 4:
        fragment = new admin_fragment_schedule();
        break;
}
initiateFragment();

return false;
}


private void clearStack(){
int count = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
while(count > 0){
    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    count--;
}
```

Comment: just add background color? how do you remove this fragment?

Comment: Please see update #2

Comment: scale down the images please.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: still, it overlaps so maybe set some background for fragment? every "switch" is removing fragments using `clearStack()`, is it working? can you produce situation with three fragments overlaping? as far as I know `ft.replace(...);` is actually replacing... dobra sugestia Marcin

Comment: adding background for fragment would be a workaround, not actually what i m trying to achieve

Comment: it will not be workaround, you just have this logic in your app... xml fixed `RecyclerView` and fragments on top of this layout. if you want to switching (not overlaping) between "screens" just put `RecyclerView` and related logic in separated `Fragment` and switch between fragments. for proper handling back press check out `Activity`s method `onBackPressed`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
private void initiateFragment(){
    if (fragment != null) {
        FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container_body);
        frameLayout.removeAllViews();
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: This piece of code does avoid overlapping, but when i press back to go back to main activity, the view is gone and main activity is blank. any workaround?

Comment: instead of `frameLayout.removeAllViews()` you may `setVisibility(View.GONE)` for your `RecyclerView` and `View.VISIBLE` when needed to show (probably in place related with `clearStack` method)